# Volume of convex polytope

Tags: definition, volume, math-software, polytopes, arc-length

Let the very simple convex polytope $P$ be given by
$$
P=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<x<1\land 0<y<1 \land x+y=1\right\}.
$$

Geometrically, this is a diagonal in the unit square and has length $\sqrt{2}$.

I used different software packages to compute the volume of $P$.

**Mathematica:**

In Wolfram's Mathematica we can define

```
P=ImplicitRegion[0<x<1 && 0<y<1 && x+y==1,{x,y}]
```

and then `Integrate[1,{x,y}\[Element] P]` will yield $\sqrt{2}$.

**LattE integrale:**

The polytope $P$ can be described by the matrix inequality $A\mathbf{x}<\mathbf{b}$, where
$$
\mathbf{x}=\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right),\quad A=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&0\\1&0\\0&-1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right), \quad \mathbf{b}=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right),
$$
and the additional linear constraint $x+y=1$. This can be specified as the [LattE integrale](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/) input file

```
5 3
0 1 0
1 -1 0
0 0 1
1 0 -1
1 -1 -1
linearity 1 5
```

The call

```
integrate filename --valuation=volume
```

gives answer 1.

**Naive computation:**

Naively one could compute the volume as
$$
\int_{P}1 = \int\int{\mathbf{1}_{(x,y)\in P}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}=\int\int{\mathbf{1}_{\left\{0<x<1 \land 0<y<1 \land x+y=1\right\}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}
$$
Replacing $y$ by $1-x$, (and dropping the $y$-integral) this "simplifies" to
$$
\int{\mathbf{1}_{\left\{0<y<1\right\}}\mathrm{d}y}=1.
$$

**Question:** What is the volume of $P$? Do the two different answers $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ reflect different notions of "volume" in this context, or merely a computational mistake on my  part?

Comment: The volume of $P$ is zero. Perhaps you meant $x+y \le 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Your original double integral is 0, since you are finding the area of a line :)
To get the correct value, look at the curve $y = 1-x$ and getting the arc length would [require changing the integrand](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx) to
$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx
   = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + (-1)^2} dx = \sqrt{2} \int_0^1 dx = \sqrt{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. But why does LattE output 1? Does it compute something different or is it just wrong?

Comment: It seems LattE is done for counting how many integer coordinate points you have in a polyhedron. But here you are looking for a volume... It's not the same.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. There are two lattice points in $P$, which is in agreement with what LattE's `count` function returns. `integrate --valuation=volume` should return the volume.